# Menu position messed up in DNN 6

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

My DNN module has some imagebuttons that show a sub-menu when clicked. The absolute position of the menu is calculated using javascript, as expected. This has worked well till now (In DNN4 and DNN5). But we are noticing a problem in DNN6. The menu position is off by a significant number of pixels (probably a couple hundred).
Since I did not write the calculation code, and neither am I a JS expert, I cannot understand how DNN6 is affecting it.
Here is the function:

```
function AbsolutePosition(obj) {
        var pos = null;
        if(obj != null) {
            pos = new Object();
            pos.top = obj.offsetTop;
            pos.left = obj.offsetLeft;
            pos.width = obj.offsetWidth;
            pos.height= obj.offsetHeight;
            obj = obj.offsetParent;
            while(obj != null) {
                pos.top += obj.offsetTop;
                pos.left += obj.offsetLeft;
                obj = obj.offsetParent;
            }
        }
return(pos);
}
```

I would like to understand how this code can be affected by the parent page structure - because changing the skin did not make any difference. This has something to do with how page elements are organized.

Edit: And I am also looking for suggestions regarding any modifications to the code that I could try.

Any input appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with how absolute positioning works.  When an element is absolutely positioned, its position (indicated by the `top` and `left` elements in the code above) is relative to its closest ancestor with a `position` style of either `relative` or `absolute`.  In DNN 6, module wrappers now have `position: relative` specified on them (which the new action menu uses for positioning).  There might also be some similar changes for the new control panel (if the menu isn't in a module).

You might try this script, which stops climbing the tree if the element's position is `absolute` or `relative`:

```
function AbsolutePosition(obj) {
    if (!obj) {
        return null;
    }

    var pos = {
        top: obj.offsetTop,
        left: obj.offsetLeft,
        width: obj.offsetWidth,
        height: obj.offsetHeight
    },
    positionsToStopAt = {
        relative: true,
        absolute: true
    };

    obj = obj.offsetParent;
    while(obj && !positionsToStopAt[jQuery(obj).css('position')]) {
        pos.top += obj.offsetTop;
        pos.left += obj.offsetLeft;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Although I do not fully understand the implications of position:relative, could you please suggest any modifications to the code that I could try?